# Defining CRS with tifffile - export .tif

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, splitting

I am trying to figure out how to define/keep my images CRS throughout a splitting script I have written. I tried adding `metadata={'init': 'epsg:3857'}` when calling `tifffile.imsave(dir_out, image)`, but when I view the split images in QGIS, the CRS is still undefined.

Is there something I am missing here?

```
import os
import tifffile

def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = tifffile.imread(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))

    windowsize_r = 10000
    windowsize_c = 10000

    i = 0
    for r in range(0, img.shape[0] - windowsize_r, windowsize_r):
        for c in range(0, img.shape[1] - windowsize_c, windowsize_c):
            window = img[r:r + windowsize_r, c:c + windowsize_c]
            out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{ext}')
            tifffile.imsave(out, window, metadata={'init': 'epsg:3857'})
            i = i + 1

tile('Orthomosaic_export_MonFeb01193821460106.tif',
     r'D:\ortho',
     r'D:\model_images')
```

It seems that when I am slicing my image `window = img[r:r + windowsize_r, c:c + windowsize_c]` that extent is what is being saved in place of my image. When in fact I want the extent from the image.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: use `rasterio` instead, as it's specifically tailored for working with geospatial imagery

Comment: So the problem with rasterio is when create a batch file with it, I get this weird cannot import gdal._version error. More can be found here about that error that seems to kind of be hit and miss with people: https://github.com/conda-forge/rasterio-feedstock/issues/149

Comment: I also cannot use `pillow` because I am working with BigTiffs and pillow does not support BigTiffs as of now. So I am kind of stuck with `tifffile` as far as I know.

Comment: If it were me I'd work through how to properly install/invoke rasterio instead of pivoting to using a potentially less suitable library.  It has APIs that fit your specific use case of [reading/writing windows](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html) and maintaining a proper transform in the output.  Your current code doesn't attempt to handle that last bit, you're just writing a bare numpy array to TIFF without any information to georeference it

Comment: I will give rasterio another try, but have installed it multiple ways and have multiple forums, but just haven't been able to get it to work. It will work if I run it by itself in say Pycharm, but if I "batch" it with other scripts, then it throughs the error.

Comment: I really think you should try to get rasterio working correctly. Usually that error is because the user is trying to use a library without activating the environment correctly.